# Core Image shader language conversion to metal with simulator support

Tags: ios, swift, metal, core-image

My app has a handful of Core Image shaders written in the Core Image Shader Language. I load them like `CIColorKernel(source: <kernel string here>)`. I just bumped the deployment target of my app from iOS 11.0 to 12.0. Now I get the following warnings.

```
'init(source:)' was deprecated in iOS 12.0: Core Image Kernel Language API deprecated. (Define CI_SILENCE_GL_DEPRECATION to silence these warnings)
```

Because our app is built with treat warnings as errors I have to hide or fix this warning.

I could rewrite the shaders in the metal shader language so I can use `CIColorKernel(functionName: <name>, fromMetalLibraryData: <data>)`, however Metal isn't supported in the simulator. So if I do that, then we won't be able to get screenshots of all the devices we need from the simulator. I could rewrite the shaders in metal and only load the metal ones when running on the device, falling back to the current ones on the simulator. However this doesn't seem ideal as we then have 2 sets of functions to maintain. This also requires I get the deprecation warning hidden somehow.

So any suggestions of a non-deprecated way to write shaders you can run in the simulator? If not I may just try to silence the warnings until iOS 13 and hope the sim gets better support. I can't figure out how to `Define CI_SILENCE_GL_DEPRECATION to silence these warnings`. I've tried adding a `CI_SILENCE_GL_DEPRECATION` build setting.

**Update**
Since it was end of the year I used one of our 2 DTS tickets to ask Apple how to silence it. Their response was to use `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations”` in an Objective-C file to disable all deprecated warnings, or file a bug about not being able to silence this one. :( I guess for now I'll just have to leave that framework's deployment target at iOS 11 for now, and hope I don't need to upgrade to 12 for some future feature/bug. The main app's deployment target can still be 12 though, so for now it won't effect users.

Comment: Given the current state of the class, looks like the simplest solution would be to silence the warning for now and cross fingers for an actual replacement, or Metal support in the simulator, in the future. A few other deprecations in that area makes it look like Apple wants to drop that GL based feature altogether, in line with their deprecation of OpenGL on MacOS/iOS platforms.

Comment: I ran into the same thing. In my ObjC class, I tried #define CI_SILENCE_GL_DEPRECATION 1 and then I tried #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations" but neither got rid of the warning. Finally, I removed the #define and it finally quieted down.

Comment: In iOS 13 Simulator now supports Metal when running on macOS 10.15, including CoreImage kernels.

Note: There is a bug in seed 1/2 that prevents CoreImage Metal kernels from working. You will see a "Metal DAG compiler disabled" error at runtime. This will be resolved in a future seed.

Comment: So since I asked this question I eventually made a Metal port of my kernels while also keeping the older OpenGL kernels for simulator support. I've verified that on macOS 10.15 running the iOS 13 simulator that my Metal kernels work. So I'll be able to delete the OpenGL kernels once iOS 13/macOS 10.15 ship this fall.

Comment: While migrating my project from iOS 12 to iOS 12 & 13 (deployment target and SDK respectively), I undid my iOS 11 deployment target hack and forgot why I did it. I then luckily found my comment right above the error and realized that some iOS 12 supported devices like iPhone 5s don't support metal. So just removing the OpenGL isn't actually possible until maybe iOS 14 comes out. Sigh...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To silence the warning add to GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS of your build configuration CI_SILENCE_GL_DEPRECATION[image: CI_SILENCE_GL_DEPRECATION]

Comment: Perfect, just tried it and it let me increase the deployment target from 11 to 12.

Comment: How long this API will be available ?